# google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess). onSuccess doesn't works inside constructor

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine, web-applications

I have a little problem with using client-server communication in Google Apps Script Web App.

My code.gs contains:

```
function loadPetName() {
  Logger.log('Client ask a Pet Name');

  // use Google apps UserProperties as default storage
  var storage = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

  return JSON.parse(storage.getProperty('name');
}
```

Pet.html is:

```
<script>
// CLASS Pet
function Pet() {

  // CONSTRUCTOR
  console.log('Creating new Pet');
  var petName;

  // Get pet name from outer storage
  console.log('Loading pet name from storage...');
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessLoad).loadPetName();
  var onSuccessLoad = function(name) {
    console.log('run onSuccessLoad');
    this.petName = name;
    alert('Pet Name is ' + name)
  };

  // METHODS ...
}
</script>
```

init.html is:

```
<script>
function init() {
  console.log('Initialization');
  var cat = new Pet();
}
</script>
```

index.html contains:

```
<body onload=init()>
  ...
```

After index.html opened in browser I see in console:

```
Initialization
Creating new Pet
Loading Pet Name from storage...
```

But there is no "run onSuccessLoad".

In Google Script console we can see: "Client ask a Pet Name". All works fine, but onSuccessLoad function isn't run.

If in Pet.html we replace

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessLoad).loadPetName();
```

to

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(console.log('SuccessHandler fired')).loadPetName();
```

We will see in console: "SuccessHandler fired".

Where is my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake... OMG!

This code doesn't work:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessLoad).loadPetName();

var onSuccessLoad = function(name) {
  console.log('run onSuccessLoad');
  this.petName = name;
};
```

But this code works fine:

```
var onSuccessLoad = function(name) {
  console.log('run onSuccessLoad');
  this.petName = name;
};

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessLoad).loadPetName();
```

But WHY?! (Sorry for the stupid question).